# Libgdx Filling Screen With Image

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm new to Libgdx and am having some problems filling an image to the entire screen. If I import a 1900x1200 image, it fills the screen, but if instead the image is 1024x512, the image is not stretched to the screen. The following is the code I've used. I thought that ''background.setSize(stageWidth, stageHeight)'' would scale the image to the screen but this doesn't happen. Could you please inform me of what I'm doing wrong? I've tried toggling with the ''setFillParent'' (as mentioned in another post) but it still doesn't work. Here's also included a screenshot of what currently appears (both on the Desktop implementation and Android): http://tinypic.com/r/b7j20z/8

Thank You for your help!

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.PerspectiveCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.MoveToAction;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.StretchViewport;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport;

public class MyGdxGame implements ApplicationListener{      

    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void create() {        
        stage = new Stage();

        float stageHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        float stageWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();

        // Background
        Texture board = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/frame.png"));
        Image background = new Image(board);
        background.setOrigin(0, 0);
        background.setSize(stageWidth, stageHeight);
        background.rotateBy(0);
        background.setPosition(0, 0);
        stage.addActor(background);

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {       
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you toggling `setFillParent` for the stage, or for the image?

Comment: I toggled it for the image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After thinking about it for a bit, the most likely cause of your problem is that you're adding  your image directly to the root of the stage. The root of the stage is a Group that doesn't handle any kind of layout managing, which is probably why your image isn't sized correctly.

I'd recommend instead that you create a `Table`, and then use `setFillParent()` so it takes up the entire screen. You can then simply use the Table's built in function, `table.background(drawable)`, to set a background. However, you have to keep in mind that a `Texture` doesn't count as drawable for the table, so you have to use the class `TextureRegionDrawable` to get a valid drawable for the background. Here's an example:

```
table.background(new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(board)));
```